# OpenId connect. User not logged out of OP google, when user signs out in RP

Tags: openid, openid-connect, google-signin

we have implemented openId connect (google+) for logging in our enterprise application and we have a security concern

Lets assume User is using a public computer from internet cafe, logs in the application(In background user signs in to google), do whatever the user wants and while signing out, User signs out only from my application. But user is still logged in to google. user is unaware that he is signed in to google and when user completes the work, User leaves the google account signed in for others. I understand user ought to know that he has to sign out from google manually and this is s a standard industry practice . But I personally feel this is a security concern and want my application automatically take care of this problem .

I prefer one of the following solution for this particular problem, but not sure whether this is possible. Please tell me is there anyway that i can achieve the solutions or suggest any other better solution for this problem.

**Solution1:**

**Scenario 1: User not logged in to Google :**
    when the User clicks sign in button, application redirected to google log in page and User signs in to google and using the details given by google, User redirects to my application and signs in to my application. Before redirecting back to my application I want google to be logged out i.e., user should not be able to access any of the google products in the current session or in any other session.

**Session 2: User logged in to google in the browser :**
    when the User clicks sign in button, application gets information from google in backend and signs in to my application. And while signing out from my application, I don't want google to be logged out as user is already signed into google and not signing in to google as a step to sign in to my application.

**Solution2:**

**Scenario 1: User not logged in to Google :**
    when the User clicks sign in button, application redirected to google log in page. User signs in to google and Using the details given by google, User redirects to my application and signs in to my application. User can access any of the google products in the current session. But while signing out of my application, i want to send some info to google, which signs out from google also.

**Session 2: User logged in to google in the browser :**
    When the User clicks sign in button, application gets information from google in back end and signs in to my application. But while signing out of my application, i want to send some info to google, which signs out from google also.

I prefer solution1 as in solution2, user is logged out of google, without his concern. I researched a lot before posting this question and found undocumented ways(like calling logout url of google) to acheive solution2. I rather prefer documented way to do this. Whether openId provided any API to do this?

Comment: Have you gone through OpenID Connect session management document -  http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html It define an end session endpoint. But I doubt Google provide that